# How can I solve getting undefined length and entries when I acess array in Angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, string, express

I do an http.get of a JSON in this format (to get it as an array of strings):

[{"_id":"605399e2d8be7837b42a4de7"},{"_id":"605399e2d8be7837b42a4de8"}]

with this function:

```
    getPetsIds(): Array<string> {
        var petIdsObs = this.http.get<any[]>(this.petsUrl)
          .pipe(
            tap(_ => this.log('fetched pets')),
            catchError(this.handleError<any[]>('getPets', []))
          );
    
        var petIds = Array<string>();
        let i = 0;
        var newPetId: string;
        petIdsObs.subscribe(b => {
          for(i; i < b.length; i++) {
            petIds.push(b[i]["_id"]);
        }
        });
        
        return petIds;
      }
```

When I console.log the resulting array it I get this:
[!console.log of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGWrv.png)

The problem is that if I access it in any other way, I get undefined.
An example would be:
`petIds.length`
or
`petIds[0]`

How do I actually access the array?

Comment: can you share the whole code with the successful console.log and the the other console.log error?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to access to an empty array that has not been filled, the observable is not yet resolved when you return the `petIds`. There is no way to return the array without the observable or a promise.

You could try using async/await:

```
      getPetsIds(): Promise<Array<string>> {
        var petIdsObs = this.http.get<any[]>(this.petsUrl)
          .pipe(
            tap(_ => this.log('fetched pets')),
            map(res => res.map(pet => pet['_id']))
            catchError(this.handleError<any[]>('getPets', []))
          ).toPromise();
      }

    //on your component, for example on ngOnInit use the async/await
      petIds = new Array<string>();
      async ngOnInit() {
        this.petIds = await this.petService.getPetsIds();
      }
```